# Compare 2 csv files using shellscript and output the difference in a new csv file

Tags: bash, unix, ksh

(say) I have 2 csv files - file1.csv  &  file2.csv as mentioned below:

```
**file1.csv**       
ID,version,cost                        
1000,1,30     
2000,2,40     
3000,3,50     
4000,4,60  



**file2.csv**      
ID,version,cost     
1000,1,30       
2000,2,45     
3000,4,55   
6000,5,70
```

The expected o/p is a new csv file say - file3.csv should contain the details of IDs which are present in both the files but with some of the data related to it being different (here version and cost) - as shown below.

```
ID,field,old,new  
2000,cost,40,45     
3000,version,3,4    
3000,cost,50,55
```

**I need a `unix` `bash/ksh` script for doing this**. I tried with `sed/grep` but could not get the proper o/p. Please help me out.

Comment: `awk` or `perl` would be better tools for this. Give it a try and post your attempt.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for ur inputs... I tried this code...
`awk -F, 'NR==FNR{_1[$1]++;next}!_1[$1]' file1.csv file2.csv > file3.csv` 
and got this o/p:
6000,5,70 (The unique line in file2)
As I am new to unix environment I m happy that I atleast got some o/p. But it's not at all in the required (o/p) format. Please suggest what can be done.

Comment: You're not saving the other fields or comparing them.

Comment: That script just prints the IDs in file2 that aren't in file1.

Comment: if your unix installation supports `join` that would be another option

Comment: K.. I think I need to go through the `awk` thoroughly ....

Comment: I hope I can somehow manage handling the differences between 2 files by studying awk. But my doubt is how can I use the 1st column as a reference column for listing the difference in other related columns :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the most elegant of solutions, but it should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

csv1=file1.csv
csv2=file2.csv

echo "ID,field,old,new"
while read line; do
  grep "$line" "$csv2" >/dev/null && continue
  id=`echo "$line" | cut -d, -f1`
  grep "^$id," "$csv2" >/dev/null || continue
  version1=`echo "$line" | cut -d, -f2`
  cost1=`echo "$line" | cut -d, -f3`
  version2=`grep "^$id," "$csv2" | cut -d, -f2`
  cost2=`grep "^$id," "$csv2" | cut -d, -f3`
  if [ "$version1" != "$version2" ]; then
    echo "$id,version,$version1,$version2"
  fi
  if [ "$cost1" != "$cost2" ]; then
    echo "$id,cost,$cost1,$cost2"
  fi
done < "$csv1"
```

Comment: You should ensure `$csv2` line *starts* with `$id`, not just contains it.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers This code works fine when the field names(i.e column names) are fixed in the first row and these column names are hardcoded into the script.
But what if I don't know how many columns(fields) both the files have (considering both files have same no. of fields and they match one-to-one)
Please post if you can write a generalized code...

Comment: @Gaman99 I provided you with a working sample, but I'm not going to do all the work you're getting paid to do.